Two sample difference of mean test when the samples come from time series
I have two sets of observations, A and B groups. I can use the t-tests to test the hypothesis that the mean of group B is larger than group A. But the inherent assumption here is that the samples in the two groups are independent. What if the samples come from two time series. Then, they are correlated and the assumption that they are independent is no longer valid. Is it possible to modify the test to account for the auto-correlation? If the correlation coefficients can be estimated somehow, then the variance used in the two sample t-test can be adjusted. I couldn't readily find any good references for this. There are some standard tests to see if one of the series predicts the other, but nothing I could find compares the means or other summary statistics.

If you are comparing the menas of A and B, it assumes that you are measuring the same thing, in the same units, on A and B. Now, the fact that they are both time series, and even sampled at the exact same frequency, does not necessarily imply correlation? E.g. I can measure the takt time of 2 production lines, in parallel, and have independent measurements. Can you clarify why in your case, there would be correlation?

Because the data points from A group are from a time series, there is correlation between them. The auto-correlation of any time series. Meaning they aren't independent samples. Same for the B group data points. The t-test assumes that the samples in the two groups are independent. This influences the variance calculation.

To achieve the targetted mean comparison, we could take the difference of the two time-series $T_A$ and $T_B$, $T_{B-A}$ and use a GLS to account for underlying correlation structures more aggressively. That way, we not only estimate the regression with $T_{B-A}$ as the response and also allow the errors of it to be correlated and/or have unequal variances. Assuming we are using R's nlme package, there is a wealth of correlation classes and variance classes to choose from. To emphasize something here: by using  $T_{B-A}$ we are focusing on the mean difference between the two time-series $T_A$ and $T_B$, not the difference of the means of each time-series. That is a natural consequence of working with time-series data, as the difference of the means ignores any time-dependencies.
(A quick-and-dirty way to determine the correlation structure is to examine the standardised residuals for a simple regression, fit an ARMA on them and then use that specification in the GLS.)

What is the first paragraph to achieve?

The third paragraph is neither clear. Non-parametric alternatives do not account for auto-correlation explicitly, but they might still be useful in relation to auto-correlation in some other ways?

Fair points (+1 to both), thanks. For the first paragraph, I was somewhat pulled to the idea that we make the series stationary. You are right, I left it hanging. Probably will delete. For the third paragraph, yes. That's the point. I will make it more explict.

Actually, I didn't like the third paragraph either, I have seen some Wilcoxon rank-based tests for clustered data and I assumed that they could be used here too but the clustering (e.g. via clustrank) still doesn't account for the autocorrelation properly.
